# Remote PHP Login with CURL in Udemy

Tags: php, curl, authentication, autologin

I've been facing problem in logging into Udemy website using CURL.
Here's my code. 
First there was some problem with the security code, "crsf" which I tried to resolve by obtaining it from "teach" url. and then tried logging in. But failed.
Please help me through this. Thanks.

```
$url="https://www.udemy.com/teach/"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html =  curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMxpath($dom);
// $x("//input[@name='csrf']/@value")
$csrfQuery = $xpath->query("//input[@name='csrf']/@value");
$csrf = $csrfQuery->item(0)->nodeValue;

$values["email"] = "some_email";
$values["password"] = "some_password";
$username = trim($values["email"]);
$password = trim($values["password"]);

$dir = "/store";
$path = $dir;

//login form action url
$postinfo = "isSubmitted=1&csrf=".$csrf."&email=".urlencode($username)."&password=".urlencode($password)."&displayType=json";

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to perform this sort of activity on their website? Because their ToS make it very clear that you are not allowed to perform any sort of scraping/automation.

Comment: Don't call curl_init twice, you'll lose your session cookies.